# How to update the content of a string list, thank's to a List View of EditText

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am trying to display a modifiable List of string thank's to a ListView of EditText.

```
public class XXX extends Activity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;
    ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Add); 
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(AddClickListener);        

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_ofPeoples, m_listItems);
        lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
    }

    private OnClickListener AddClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {           
            m_listItems.add(new String("toto"));
            m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

The layout "ListOfPeople" is simply an Edit Text :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/people">
</EditText>
```

With this code, when I click on the button, a new EditText is added with the string "Toto".

My m_listItems is well bounded with the listView thank's to the m_adapter !

But how to do the reverse bind (or link) ?

When I modify the content of the first EditText, I would like that the content of the first string of m_listItems be modified acordingly to the EditText...

Any help will be apreciated,
Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your notifyDataSetChanged() immediately after setAdapter() like this..

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
m_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_ofPeoples, m_listItems);
lv.setAdapter(m_adapter);
m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```